# How to query the highest invoice number field from the mongodb database using express server nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, graphql

I'm trying to query a user's last or latest invoice number from the mongodb database using nodejs express server and graphql as my entry point which I can store in my state

I've to query all the invoice and tried to extract the highest number but with no luck

```
  invoiceNumbers: async () => {
    try {
      const invoiceNumbers = await Invoice.find().limit();
      return invoiceNumbers.map(invoiceNumber => {
        const newInvoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
        return transfromInvoice(newInvoiceNumber);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new Error(error);
    }   }
```

> But however when I run the query I tend to get all my documents
>   instead of getting the highest invoice number.
>
> E.g "There is Invoice Number 1, 2 and 3 in the database. When I run
>   the query it will return all of those document instead of returning
>   the highest invoice number which is 3"

Comment: use `reduce` (instead of `map`) to find max number - not graphql/mongo problem - pure js ... but generally bad idea, api should return next/new number

Comment: Hi I've never used `reduce`  could you please illustrate for me on how to use it - @xadm

Comment: use for loop if learning/searching for sth new is too much